# Tuleap "project data export" does not work

Tags: tuleap

Project data export link shows a blank page when I click on the link (Project data export) under the project administration

Latest full version of tuleap is installed on centOs 6.3 (virtual box instance)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?aid=8012

The corresponding fix is integrated into Tuleap 8.0.99.45 ; given that Tuleap is developed under continuous deployment this version will be available at some point during the 17th April 2015.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I will waiting for the updates patch/package/version. And can you let me know how to install that

Comment: Hi, you should follow the upgrade procedure http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/installation-guide/update.html

Comment: Thanks I was able to upgrade successfully and the project data export link is also working. But inside the project data export link I do not see ‘Generate Full Project Database’ link to generate a snapshot of your project data.